# Using generic object methods in generic class

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a generic class in which the generic type itself can have methods.

This is what I did in Java:

```
public class DepthFirstPaths <GraphType> implements PathInterface
{
    private final int start;        

    public DepthFirstPaths (GraphType G, int s)
    {
        int vCount = G.numVertex(); //This line is giving errors
        start = s;

        DFS(G, s);
    }

    //Other methods
    ....
}
```

GraphType can refer to a directed graph type or undirected graph type and this is because DFS does the same thing for both types of graphs given a source vertex. But the above java code gives errors like:

```
Description: The method numVertex() is undefined for the type GraphType
Resource: DepthFirstPaths.java
Path: /Paths/src/GraphAlgorithms
Location: line 17
Type: Java Problem
```

Plus other errors relating to using `GraphType object` methods in the code

What can I do to fix this? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I guess you are porting some C++ code to java...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definition

```
public class DepthFirstPaths <GraphType>
```

Means your generic type name is `GraphType`.

To make your class always work with a `GraphType`, you should mark your generic extends from `GraphType`:

```
public class DepthFirstPaths <T extends GraphType>
```

Then just use `T` in your code to refer to the generic:

```
public class DepthFirstPaths <T extends GraphType> implements PathInterface {
    private final int start;        

    public DepthFirstPaths (T G, int s) {
        //This line won't give you errors anymore
        //except if GraphType doesn't have a numVertex method
        int vCount = G.numVertex();
        start = s;

        DFS(G, s);
    }

    //Other methods
    ....
}
```

Comment: So say I have the 2 graph classes: undirGraph and dirGraph, do I have to write: `public class DepthFirstPaths <T extends undirGraph, dirGraph>`?

Comment: If `UndirGraph` and `DirGraph` classes extend from `GraphType`, you won't need to do that.

Comment: Aha, I see. So I have to somehow make all Graph objects extend GraphType then I can use your above syntax? So what should GraphType be? interface? Abstract class?

Comment: That will depend on your design but IMO it should be an interface. You can define such design based on the `List` interface and `ArrayList` class implementation.